# preventDefault in JS not working when fetch API upload files

Tags: javascript, file-upload, fetch, preventdefault

I have been trying to create a simple web app where you can post images and a little description. It is for an Instagram Clone project. I am using multer and express on the backend to parse the body and the file, and it works perfectly fine. The problem is on the frontend. I provide a form where you put name, description and the image to upload, then with the Fetch API I send the body to my api on the backend.

I noticed that the page reloads every time I submit the form despite the use of event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() for the form sumbit event.

In addition, I have realised that it does so only when also uploading the file, in fact, if I leave the name and description alone, it doesn't reload the page, whereas if I live the file upload in there it just reloads it.

Is this a bug of the fetch API or am I not considering something?

Here's the code on the frontend that handles the fetch request to my api:

```js
const instaForm = document.getElementById("post-pic");

instaForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  let instaFormData = new FormData(instaForm);

  let url = `${baseUrl}/create-insta`;

  fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: instaFormData,
  })
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((response) => {
      instaForm.reset();
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
});
```

Consider that if I leave the input for the file blank, the page doesn't reload so it is definitely a problem with the file upload.

For now, for debugging my API is sending back a simple "Received" response and nothing else.

HTML Form

```
<form method="POST" id="post-pic" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input
          type="text"
          id="name"
          name="name"
          placeholder="Enter a name..."
        />
        <textarea
          name="description"
          id="description"
          rows="10"
          placeholder="A short description..."
        ></textarea>
        <input type="file" id="picture" name="insta" />
        <button id="publish" type="submit">Publish</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like? If you have HTML5 validation on the fields (e.g. `required` attributes), the `submit` event doesn't get fired if those fail.

Comment: None of the fields is required from the HTML. I usually do it with javascript.

Comment: [Edit] your question with the HTML formatted as code.

Comment: Check your console for errors

Answer (score 1):

You should catch the event when clicking on the form button.

Try this:

```
<form method="POST" id="post-pic" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input
      type="text"
      id="name"
      name="name"
      placeholder="Enter a name..."
    />
    <textarea
      name="description"
      id="description"
      rows="10"
      placeholder="A short description..."
    ></textarea>
    <input type="file" id="picture" name="insta" />
    <button id="publish" type="button">Publish</button>
  </form>
```

JS Script:

```
const instaForm = document.getElementById("post-pic");

const buttonForm = document.getElementById("publish");

buttonForm.addEventListener("click",(event) => {

  event.preventDefault();

  let instaFormData = new FormData(instaForm);

  let url = `${baseUrl}/create-insta`;
  
  fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  body: instaFormData,
  })
  .then((data) => data.json())
  .then((response) => {
   instaForm.reset();
   console.log(response);
   })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
   });

}
```

I hope it could help you.
Regards.

Comment: Actually, it does work. It's a clever workaround. I have changed my code now because I really cannot find the answer. However, I am still quite confused as to whether this is a fetch API bug, an HTML bug, or something else. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to be of help @BeGeos, you could improve a little your code to be more readable moving from promises (.then().then().catch()  to asyn/await (Async function () => { await fetch response }).
There is a link if your want to take a look: [Convert A Promise To ASYNC/AWAIT - Dev.to.](https://dev.to/marsou001/convert-a-promise-to-async-await-3gd5)